# Enabling GPU on Windows 10 X1 Carbon box results in frequent search index corruption

Tags: windows-10, gpu, search, lenovo-laptop, windows-search

I've had problems with frequent Windows search index corruption over many years and four generations of X1 Carbon boxes. I'm currently on the highest end 10th gen (2022) carbon, Win10 22H2 (19045.2311). The phenomenon is annoying because it takes a couple of days for the index to rebuild (more than 2 million items) and in the meantime Outlook can't be searched reliably.

One fix that eliminates the problem 100% reproducibly is to disable the Intel Iris XE Graphics driver in device manager, which (I believe) in turn disables the GPU. But of course then I suffer degraded performance.

A typical occurrence includes these events:

```
SearchIndexer (13192,D,0) Windows: An attempt to write to the file "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\edb.jtx" at offset 765952 (0x00000000000bb000) for 12288 (0x00003000) bytes failed after 0.000 seconds with system error 1453 (0x000005ad): "Insufficient quota to complete the requested service. ".  The write operation will fail with error -1011 (0xfffffc0d).  If this error persists then the file may be damaged and may need to be restored from a previous backup.
SearchIndexer (13192,D,10) Windows: Unable to write to section 2 while flushing logfile C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\edb.jtx. Error -1011 (0xfffffc0d).
SearchIndexer (13192,D,10) Windows: The logfile sequence in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\" has been halted due to a fatal error. No further updates are possible for the databases that use this logfile sequence. Please correct the problem and restart or restore from backup.
The search service has detected corrupted data files in the index {id=4811 - onecoreuap\base\appmodel\search\search\search\propstore\propsess.cxx (155)}. The service will attempt to automatically correct this problem by rebuilding the index. 
The Windows Search Service is being stopped because there is a problem with the indexer: The catalog is corrupt. 
SearchIndexer (13192,D,9) Windows: The database engine detected multiple threads illegally using the same database session to perform database operations. 
The search service has detected corrupted data files in the index {id=4810 - onecoreuap\base\appmodel\search\search\ytrip\common\util\jetutil.cpp (653)}. The service will attempt to automatically correct this problem by rebuilding the index.
```

Note the "quota" error must be a red herring--I have no quota configured on my drive, which is an internal 1TB SSD (Samsung MZVL210THCLR-00BL7) with more than 500GB available. FWIW, Windows.edb is about 27GB when indexing completes.

I have tried all the low hanging fruit:

- Buying new laptops and starting from scratch over several years
- Reinstalling or restoring Windows
- Installing all Windows, Lenovo, and Intel Updates (I've tried both OEM drivers and the latest Windows and Intel drivers -- makes no difference)
- sfc /scannow
- chkdsk /f
- All relevant troubleshooters (including search index troubleshooter)
- Manually deleting all search index data and allowing the device to rebuild
- Triggering a "rebuild index" from the control panel

I hit on the "solution" of disabling the GPU because the search index corruption behavior often coincided with a temporary interruption/"blank flash" of the display, nearly always when driving one or two large external HD displays connected through a USB-C dock (I've tried several display nad dock models). Disabling the GPU also prevents this other problem, and I have yet to see any search index corruption while GPU is disabled.

I have spent months trying to troubleshoot this with Lenovo to no avail. I've also filed an incident with Microsoft but doubt I will get any useful feedback.

Any ideas on how to isolate the cause and solve this other than by disabling GPU?

Comment: Thank you for all the troubleshooting you have done.  I comment only to say I have 2 X1s here: 1 4th was Windows 10 now Windows 11 Insider and 1 9th Windows 11, both with Intel Graphics and Samsung 1 TB SSD drives.  Indexing and searching works fine.  I will continue to look at this

Comment: @John, how big is your search index? I realize 2 million search items is on the large side (mostly because I have a lot of email stored in many historical PSTs) but not beyond what MS should support. But I do wonder if the size of my index and edb could be a factor, since that is one of the few things that has been constant across several X1 Carbon models and fresh reinstalls.

Comment: My Index is about 200K items. I have never been as large as 2 M items. Index Size might be a factor.  Try Windows 11 Pro on the newest machine to see if it handles that size of index.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

[Maximum Index Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/windows-search-performance-issues)

> **Number of items indexed**
>
> On a typical user's computer, the Indexer indexes fewer than 30,000
> items. On a power user's computer, the Indexer might index up to
> 300,000 items. If the Indexer indexes more than 400,000 items, you may
> begin to see performance issues. For more information, go to Size of
> the index database.
>
> **The Indexer can index up to 1 million items.** If the Indexer tries to index beyond that limit, it may fail or cause resource problems on
> the computer (such as high usage of CPU, memory, or disk space).
>
> **Note**
>
> By default, the Indexer indexes any Outlook mailboxes on the computer.
> If a mailbox contains more than 6 million items, the performance of
> the Indexer may degrade. For more information, go to the "Change
> Outlook settings" section.
>
> To check the number of indexed items, select Settings > Search >
> Searching Windows, and then check the value of Indexed items.

.

I am confident then, that the size of your index is too large and is more likely your problem than the Intel GPU.

It is reasonable that the much reduced GPU load by disabling the GPU (with attendant bad performance) is just loosely related to the crashing. The size of your index is the real problem and manifested itself on multiple computers.

**Follow up:**  I did suggest trying Windows 11 Pro to see, and otherwise, I still think your very large index is the source of the problem because your problem occurs with different machines. Try to find a way to reduce (archive, move files, whatever) to reduce the size of your index.

Comment: The GPU behavior is 100% consistent, though. When my graphics device driver is enabled, I will get these crashes regularly, sometimes multiple times per week. With the driver disabled, I’ve gone for weeks with zero problems, and in the past year or so since I found this workaround, I’ve not once seen index corruption with GPU disabled. If the issue really is the index size, does this GPU correlation make any sense?

Also, don’t other people keep many years of email? Most of the 2M index items are email. Is there really no way to keep your email indefinitely and have a stable Windows box?

Comment: does this GPU correlation make any sense?   .... I think disabling the GPU provides enough resource for the indexing to keep going. But disabling the GPU does not seem to be a helpful long term solution. So I still think the Microsoft article makes sense.

Comment: Although there appears to be an internal conflict in that post that says the maximum size one million items, but then it indicates that performance may degrade if there are more than *six* million email items. I believe the largest chunk of my indexed items are emails and there are clearly fewer than six million of those.

Comment: I took historical PSTs out of the index so now it has 300K items. I'm still seeing behavior when GPU is enabled where the screen blacks out and some processes crash, although so far it hasn't specifically resulted in search engine corruption. The latest corresponding event log messages are faulting application: RuntimeBroker.exe; faulting module names: ucrtbase.dll, ntdll.dll, as well as 'Virtual Machine' Microsoft Virtual BIOS...: Failed to Power on with Error 'Insufficient quota to complete the requested service.' So the "insufficient quota" error is similar to the search engine error.

Comment: I spoke too soon -- after a few more "black out" events, I did get the same search index corruption error, requiring the index to be rebuilt. With only 300K items it rebuilds much faster than the 2M items it had previously, though.

Comment: I will keep this in mind. Your search index is only a bit larger than mine, safe in size, and I did not have search index corruption on Windows 10 and do not on Windows 11.  Any legacy software perhaps?

Comment: I don't think it's legacy software -- it seems particular to the situation where GPU is enabled and high DPI/resolution external monitor(s) are used. I was trying to troubleshoot this on my previous gen X1 laptop and reinstalled the stock Lenovo system image and then installed just a couple of necessary applications for testing -- webcam driver and Zoom. Still replicated the same issue under the same circumstances.

Comment: I never had this issue on either X1

Comment: Another strange observation is this phenomenon is not reproducible. Especially since I shrunk down the search index, I sometimes go 3-4 days without it happening at all, and then it will happen several times in the same day. I can't find anything in event viewer or, for example, with CPU temperature, that seems predictive of the behavior. I'd be happy to run some kind of constant monitoring task to see if there's anything I can catch that correlates with the screen disconnect, but I haven't figured out what that might be.

Comment: I have two X1 machines and do not have this issue. Try Admin Tools, Resource Monitor and see what CPU is doing over a lengthy period of time

Comment: Another data point: I disabled my webcam driver, since that is potentially the only thing that makes my setup unique, and for good measure also disabled the built-in camera driver. Same behavior recurred, so I've eliminated that as a cause.

Comment: You might consider a new (or format, install) Windows 11 Pro computer (suggested in my answer).  Start with just Office and Adobe.  Build your index and test.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a corporate box and I can't upgrade the OS. Since I was no longer using my previous gen carbon for work, I did reformat and image it with the OEM (Lenovo) system image, and still got this behavior. That was before Windows 11 was released, though, so I haven't had an opportunity to test it on that OS yet.

Comment: Tell the Company your issue (all documented here) and ask them to rebuild or give you a new Windows 11 machine

Comment: I'll see if I can make any headway with the Company. In the meantime, I just captured some real-time information with Resource Monitor when the blackout occurred. The things that jump out at me is "Memory Compression" is using 1,781 threads, and the "Memory" tab is reporting 39160 Hard Faults/second. This box has 16GB RAM and is not doing anything unusually computationally (or memory) intensive -- I have open Outlook, Word, Thunderbird, Slack. Does this provide us with any useful intel? I don't know if the high number of hard faults could be the cause of the blackout or instead a result of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142192/discussion-between-ajkessel-and-john).